# How does ControlledOnInt in Q# make it Grovers Oracle?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, q#

I have an example with 6 qubits for names and 6 for telephones. I encoded their relation like this:

```
(ControlledOnInt(1, SetRegisterToInt(6, _)))(rnames, rtels);
(ControlledOnInt(3, SetRegisterToInt(2, _)))(rnames, rtels);
```

So there are only 2 registers states(tel->name) in a BD with 64 possible states.

When I ask the BD for a name from a telephone it works ok, 6 => 2 and 2 => 3 because only in these 2 values (6 and 2) the marked qbit entangled with telephones is One.

So the important part is the oracle made with ControlledOnInt, and I need to know how does it, because I have my own Grovers in c++ and I want to know the details to make it, and also to learn what gates it uses and how it multiply the matrices.

Thanks

Comment: I mean what I need to know is which gates are used to transfrom telephone 6 in name 2 and T 2 in name 6 that are valid for both?. I supoposse there will be a comparation first to know if T is 2 or 6 and later convert their bits with CNOT?

Comment: The questions seem very broad. Are you asking about *your* implementation of Grover's applied to a $6$-qubit database of names/telephone numbers?  What is a BD?  What do you mean by 6=>2 and 2=>3?  "I have my own Grovers in c++ and I want to know the details to make it" - so did you implement Grover's algorithm, or not?   "And also to learn what gate it uses" - gates for Grover's algorithm?  Or your implementation?  "how it multiple the matrices" - how what multiplies which matrices?

Answer (score 3):

[ControlledOnInt](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.canon.controlledonint) is a library function which applies a specified operation (in this case `SetRegisterToInt`) to the target register only if the control register is in a state that encodes the given integer. Internally it does the following:

- convert the given integer to an array of bits (in little-endian format I think);
- applies X gate to each qubit that corresponds to a 0 bit in the notation of the integer;
- applies normally controlled version of the operation (apply operation if all control qubits are in $|1\rangle$ state) to the control and target registers;
- and applies X gate to each qubit that that corresponds to a 0 bit in the notation of the integer again to return control register to its starting state.

Comment: To quickly follow up on Mariia's answer, you can see the source code for ControlledOnInt at https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/blob/e6885b1949f485c669a7eeebb2bd878af29d796c/Standard/src/Canon/Utils/ControlledOnBitString.qs#L48. Essentially, ControlledOnInt uses Q#'s partial application feature together with ControlledOnBitString to implement the steps that Mariia described above.

Comment: Thanks,  yes I made my own Grovers, but to be usefull needs to entangled 2 registers. What I dont know is which gates uses in the control register to know it is name 1 or 3 . I mean this is an if () with six &&. I saw  this circuit  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiKmS.png with control and anticontrol dots. So which gates are these how to express this in quantum way?

Comment: Anyway, because the entaglement that contains the BD looks like it have to be hardware encoded with gates in the circuit, this means that for each BD u need a specific hardware. So maybe the is a initial state (not Hadamard) that maps the searched number with a unique number(state), so this circuit could be used with any BD. Or at least that it could map a lot of numbers